# Add Service Principal Name to Keytab file on Windows

Tags: windows, kerberos, spn

What command can I run on windows to add a SPN to a keytab file on Windows? It seems all the documentation I can find is for linux.

Answer (score 0):

[TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.kerberos-keytabs-explained.aspx) suggests [`ktpass`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ktpass) to create the `*.keytab` file; it also kindly explains this is not the common setup in a Windows environment.